# Jquery Menu adjusting the right dropdown

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

I am using  a wordpress jquery vertical megamenu plugin.

I have used the plugin to show the categories dropdown menu. The issue here is the  "sub container " does not position properly to the 'li'.

sub container appears little down.

```
     <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Category1</a>
            <div class="sub-container>
               <ul class="sub">
                   <li><a href="#">Category1</a></li>
                   <li><a href="#">Category2</a></li>
               </ul>  
            </div>
         <li>
        <li><a href="#">Category2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Category3</a></li>
     </ul>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Bl_praveen2004/8j99k/2/) and [working link](http://shop2build.com/free-shipping/)

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a purely css related issue. I have updated the sub-containers to have the following css

```
left:100%;
top:-1px; /* this is to combat the top border */
```

and then given the main li's a `position:relative;`

updated jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8j99k/3/

EDIT: as per the working example.. please change the following css declarations for this to work:
file: screen.css,
line: 3124

```
figcaption #dc_jqverticalmegamenu_widget-4-item ul li .sub-container{
    left:100% !important;
    top:-1px;
    margin-top:0 !important;
}
```

file: skin.php,
line:5

```
#dc_jqverticalmegamenu_widget-4-item ul li{
    position:relative;
}
```

as i mentioned above.. this is purely a css issue.. you have `!important` styles that are overriding things..

Comment: If the menu is inside a another div which is position absoulte. it is not working.

Comment: can you update your jsFiddle to include all of your code restrictions then please. this is probably still a css issue, but is related to the non-specificity of the css styles in the stylesheet

Comment: In the site the menu is inside a div which is position absolute

Comment: How to find the height of a link from the top of the div position relative?

Comment: @BLPraveen i have updated your fiddle to include a wrapper that is absolutely positioned.. it still works http://jsfiddle.net/8j99k/6/

Comment: it is working in the demo. But not working in the live. You can look into the working website link given above